# Getting error when parsing JSON by GSON using Volley

Tags: java, android, gson

How to parse below JSON using GSON library and Volley?

```
[
    {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "Scan Details",
        "result": [
            {
                "Inbound Date": "2017-10-13",
                "Outobund Date": "2017-10-16",
                "Inbound": "3",
                "Outbound": "3",
                "Outbound Pending": "0"
            },
            {
                "Inbound Date": "2017-10-16",
                "Outobund Date": "2017-10-16",
                "Inbound": "3",
                "Outbound": "2",
                "Outbound Pending": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have already created POJO classes :

**DashboardPojo_BK**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class DashboardPojo_BK implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private Integer code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<ResultDashboard_BK> result = null;

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<ResultDashboard_BK> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<ResultDashboard_BK> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

**ResultDashboard_BK**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ResultDashboard_BK implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("Inbound Date")
    @Expose
    private String inboundDate;
    @SerializedName("Outobund Date")
    @Expose
    private String outobundDate;
    @SerializedName("Inbound")
    @Expose
    private String inbound;
    @SerializedName("Outbound")
    @Expose
    private String outbound;
    @SerializedName("Outbound Pending")
    @Expose
    private String outboundPending;

    public String getInboundDate() {
        return inboundDate;
    }

    public void setInboundDate(String inboundDate) {
        this.inboundDate = inboundDate;
    }

    public String getOutobundDate() {
        return outobundDate;
    }

    public void setOutobundDate(String outobundDate) {
        this.outobundDate = outobundDate;
    }

    public String getInbound() {
        return inbound;
    }

    public void setInbound(String inbound) {
        this.inbound = inbound;
    }

    public String getOutbound() {
        return outbound;
    }

    public void setOutbound(String outbound) {
        this.outbound = outbound;
    }

    public String getOutboundPending() {
        return outboundPending;
    }

    public void setOutboundPending(String outboundPending) {
        this.outboundPending = outboundPending;
    }

}
```

This is the post request I am using here, I can able to parse data but getting issue when data is setting to POJO classes by GSON.

Below is my `JSON` parsing using Volley library.

```
 String url = Constants.BLOOMKONNECT_DASHBOARD;
    Log.e("URL",""+url);

    StringRequest eventoReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());

                    utils.hideDialog();
                    try {
                        JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);

                        // Parse a json
                        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = j.getJSONObject(0);
                                String code = String.valueOf(obj.get("code"));
                                Log.e("CODE", "" + code);

                                if(code.equals("1")){
                                    utils.showtoast("i m here");



                                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                                    Type listType = new TypeToken<ResultDashboard_BK>() {
                                    }.getType();
                                    ResultDashboard_BK pojo  = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);
                                     Log.e("DATA",""+pojo);

                                } else {
                                    utils.hideDialog();
                                    utils.showtoast("Unexpected Response");
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", "" + error.getMessage());
            //hidePDialog();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_id", userId);
            Log.e("USER_ID",""+userId);
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Añade la peticion a la cola
    AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(eventoReq);
```

**Error_Log**

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
          at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
          at com.kabloom.kbinternal.activities.BloomKnctDashboard$3.onResponse(BloomKnctDashboard.java:142)
          at com.kabloom.kbinternal.activities.BloomKnctDashboard$3.onResponse(BloomKnctDashboard.java:118)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
          at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
          at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
          at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) 
          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) 
          at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
          at com.kabloom.kbinternal.activities.BloomKnctDashboard$3.onResponse(BloomKnctDashboard.java:142) 
          at com.kabloom.kbinternal.activities.BloomKnctDashboard$3.onResponse(BloomKnctDashboard.java:118) 
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60) 
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30) 
          at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Comment: If you are getting an error, please add error log too.

Comment: I have added my error log . @AminMousavi

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598988/2940733

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was BEGIN\_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 (little edit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077649/expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2-little-edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this in your code .

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DashboardPojo_BK>>() {}.getType();
 List<DashboardPojo_BK> mList = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listType);
```

Comment: Your code solved by issue what i was getting. Thankyou

Comment: Please help me one thing more,I have to set the result data in RecyclerView.

adapter = new InOutboundAdapter(this,mList.get(0).getResult());
                                         recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
HOw i have to send arrayList to Adapter.

Comment: You can set `List<DashboardPojo_BK> mList` as global data ,and you can use it in your adapter .

Comment: I solved , One thing i have not understand when i am sending context , i have to set in constructor of adapter is  Response.Listener<String> context; previously i set Context context;

Why  i am getting context from Activity to Adapter is  Response.Listener<String> context; ?

Comment: Solved, Thanks alot @KeLiuyue

Comment: Good luck to you .@Abhishekkumar

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why root element is JsonArray but it's better to correspond for loop because of JsonArray. try the following codes.

```
try {
    JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // Parse a json
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject obj = j.getJSONObject(i);

      DashboardPojo_BK pojo = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), DashboardPojo_BK.class);

      if (pojo.getCode().equals("1")){
        utils.showtoast("i m here");

        // do somthing with pojo
      } else {
        utils.hideDialog();
        utils.showtoast("Unexpected Response");
      }

    }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this compile dependency in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

then after getting response you can parse the json to gson using following

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DashboardPojo_BK>>(){}.getType();
List<DashboardPojo_BK> responseModel = (List<DashboardPojo_BK>) gson.fromJson(response, listType);
```

//where reponse is the string you got from api response

Answer (score 1):

Your json is a JSONArray, so you need to parse `List<DashboardPojo_BK>` instead of parsing `DashboardPojo_BK` directly.